# Replace all instances of - with . until A or G or T or C from both ends of a string

Tags: awk

So for example if input is:
`-------A--GG---CCAAT---A------`
 output should be:
`.......A--GG---CCAAT---A......`
 I would prefer to do this in awk.

Comment: Have you already tried something? Do you have some example we can start from? You should at least show that you already did some searching, otherwise it would be too easy to let other people write code for you :-)

Comment: I was attempting to use ^ and $ and wildcards in various combinations with gsub but it did not lead anywhere, essentially building from: awk '{gsub(/-/, "."); print}' . It would be fine if somebody showed me how to do it from one end so I could do that and then rev and do it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be a bit complicated because `awk` does not allow you to call a function with the matched string, so you need to manually take out the matched strings (`l` and `r`), further process them, and replace `$0` with the original string plus the matched strings:

```
awk '{
    if (match($0, /^-*/)) { l = substr($0, 1, RLENGTH); gsub("-", ".", l); $0 = l substr($0, RLENGTH + 1); }
    if (match($0, /-*$/)) { r = substr($0, RSTART); gsub("-", ".", r); $0 = substr($0, 1, RSTART - 1) r; }
    print $0;
}'
```

or using `gsub` again to mutate the matched strings in `$0` instead of concatenating:

```
awk '{
    if (match($0, /^-*/)) { l = substr($0, 1, RLENGTH); gsub("-", ".", l); gsub(/^-*/, l, $0); }
    if (match($0, /-*$/)) { r = substr($0, RSTART); gsub("-", ".", r); gsub(/-*$/, r, $0); }
    print $0;
}'
```

Comment: Thanks a million. The trick was to use built-in variables I had no idea existed.

Comment: Indeed I just learned these variables in the `awk` manpage. I was looking at `match()` but then it does not return the matched string. So I attempted to reconstruct it using `RSTART` and `RLENGTH`.